# Question marks instead of Hebrew characters

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

**Question marks instead of Hebrew characters**

I'm using MVC 6 for Hebrew site. In the model classes I was insert display name for the properties. But when I run the site I get the display name as question marks.
I was checked my encoded and it set to UTF-8 than I try this on MVC 5 project and it worked as expected.

For Example:

```
public partial class Drivers
{
    [Display(Name = "מזהה")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

And in My site it look like that:  ����

Comment: What encoding does your browser report for the site? You can usually check that by right-clicking in the browser and choosing page information or something.

Comment: utf-8 this is from the page: <meta charset="utf-8" />

Comment: Is that also what the browser tells you what the *effective* encoding is?

Comment: Yes. All the encoding set to UTF-8. also from MVC-5 project is displayed correctly,

Answer (score 1):

Save the file like this:

```
File-->Advanced Safe Options->Unicode(UTF-8 with signature)-Codepage 65001
```

Then have this in web.config:

```
 <system.web>
   <globalization requestEncoding="windows-1255" responseEncoding="windows-1255" fileEncoding="windows-1255" culture="he-IL" uiCulture="he-IL" />
 </system.web>
```